# Unable to implement OnClickListener into separate Java class

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

`OnClickListener` works fine when I implement on `MainActivity` class of Java .But its a messy practice to use on same class of main interference.
So I add a separate Java class `ButtonListener.java` and wrote the following code

```
public class ButtonListener extends MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button2:
                    CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                    break;
                case R.id.button:
                    CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break; }}}
```

and following is code of `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
   public ConstraintLayout CL;
   public Button blue,green;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        blue= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        green=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        CL= findViewById(R.id.CL) ;
        ButtonListener B= new ButtonListener();

        blue.setOnClickListener(B);
        green.setOnClickListener(B);
}}
```

I am trying this code but when ever I open my app and click on the button, it crashes.

Comment: Just use `class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener` . There is nothing messy about it . No need to create a separate class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving `NullPointerException` because your `cl` is not initialized.

The `extends MainActivity` give you access to `cl` variable but it never been written to and it's completely different than `MainActivity.cl`.

What you're trying can be achieved with a custom listener (**Strong note: You do not need to extend MainActivity to implements listener**)

```
public class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ConstraintLayout CL;
    public ButtonListener(ConstraintLayout cl) {
        this.CL = cl;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // bla bla
    }
}
```

And in your `MainActivity`, replace:

```
ButtonListener B= new ButtonListener();

blue.setOnClickListener(B);
green.setOnClickListener(B);
```

With:

```
ButtonListener B= new ButtonListener(CL); // pass contraints layout here

blue.setOnClickListener(B);
green.setOnClickListener(B);
```

Comment: getting error on ButtonListener B= new ButtonListener(CL);  "Saying ButtonListner cant be applied with this parameter"

Comment: Did you add the constructor to `ButtonListener` like I did? `public ButtonListener(ConstraintLayout cl)  `

Comment: on ButtonListener.java when i removed extends MainActivity,  CL is giving error "cant resolve symbol Cl"

Comment: Check the `ConstraintLayout` variable name in `ButtonListener`:     `private ConstraintLayout CL;` . It's pretty easy to see it dude.

Comment: yup i did WRITE "ButtonListener(ConstraintLayout cl)" but it cant identify "CL" because its not present in its class.

Comment: Did you declare:     `private ConstraintLayout CL;` in `ButtonListener` class? Dude, it's about ten line of codes only, you have to read my code carefully.

Comment: refresh page and please have a look at code below in my answer

Comment: I've commented there

Answer (score 0):

You call `CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));` in the `ButtonListener` and of course it's null because it's in the `MainActivity`. You should pass the `ConstraintLayout CL` to `ButtonListener` to fix. I believe the logcat says it clear enough.

However, IMHO, I disagree that using the main class to implement any behavior of its components is bad. To me, it helps you save lots of new object allocation, passing parameters around, save class count because there may be many click listener in the app when it gets bigger.

Comment: _To me, it helps you save lots of new object allocation, passing parameters around, save class count because there may be many click listener in the app when it gets bigger._  Your concerns are wrong. You also save no object allocation. Class count is not a big deal if you organize them correctly. The activity class will be a mess and very hard to maintain if you try to add listener it over and over. You definitely should read about `Separation of concern`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For now, I agree with you on 3 things: 1-The activity will become messy with many interface implementations, 2-Separate the logic helps easier maintain in long-term, 3-Any reason I mentioned above can be easily handled by the system without any noticeable difference in performance. Things I still need to be clear out is: Why do I save no object allocation, I have to new it to use it, also passing all the required components as parameters just like @yestin has to pass the `ConstraintLayout` into the listener.

Comment: Ah in this case, you're correct about object allocation, you don't need to initialize new `OnClickListener`, that's one object allocation. About parameter passing: Passing parameters around incur minimal effort, since in java, your `ButtonListener` receiver just a reference of `ConstraintLayout` only (think like C++, it's just a pointer). If it makes your code more decoupling, do it.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion anyway. I will keep the balance between those 2 options

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ButtonListener  implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ConstraintLayout cl;
    public ButtonListener(ConstraintLayout cl) {
        this.CL = cl;
    }




    @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button2:
                    CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                    break;
                case R.id.button:
                    CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;

            }


        }}
```

problem is CL is written in RED because of error
Main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
   public ConstraintLayout CL;
   public Button blue,green;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        blue= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        green=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        CL= findViewById(R.id.CL) ;
        ButtonListener B= new ButtonListener(CL);

        blue.setOnClickListener(B);
        green.setOnClickListener(B);

    }



}
```

Comment: It's RED because you declare it as `cl` not `CL` (uppercase). Change it to `private ConstraintLayout CL;` like my code

Comment: Sorry sir, i copied that from your unedited comment didnt see you have corrected it.

Comment: what's the log/exception?

Comment: Sir you have done some magic :) its working now. but i have one question to ask

Comment: when i extends MainActivity.. Doesnt it mean  ButtonListener has all the
objects of its parent class i.e Mainactivity. like initialization of CL in MainActivity should be in ButtonListener becasue we are inheriting from it? 
anyways thanks for all your time.. MUch appreciated :)

Comment: oky thanks now i got some idea... java is a bit weird than other programming languages

Comment: You inherited properties from `MainActivity` class. But remember, your android app creates and initializes an instance of `MainActivity` (1).  Your `new ButtonListener` is a different instance of `MainActivity` (2), they (instance (1) and (2)) are not sharing their `CL` properties, unless you declare `CL` as `static` field

Comment: i declared static public ConstraintLayout CL in MainActivity , used  extends MainActivity on  ButtonListener and remove teh contructor initializer code on ButtonListener  and that works also. Thanks for your explaination, it helped me alot :)

Comment: Use of static like that is discouraged (Because if you access that variable before it's initialized will cause NullPointerException). Cheer. Mark your question as answered so other can be helped too :)